# Pressure of the generated gas in experiment

Tags: pressure, fluid-statics, gas

Considering the usual experiment, shown in the image, what would the pressure of the produced gas be? The only information we have is the volume of gas generated and its temperature, and no, we cannot use the ideal gas equation.

I’ve been trying to solve it by considering the amount of displaced water, but getting nowhere. This problem may be very simple, yet its answer has been eluding me.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The pressure at the water surface level is equal to the atmospheric pressure. This implies that the gas pressure plus the pressure of water column above the water surface is equal to the atmospheric pressure. You can easily calculate the pressure exerted by the water column and subtract that from the atmospheric pressure to get the gas pressure.

$P_{atm} = P_{gas}+\rho_w g h_w$